# ASP.NET input tags - cursor:default

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got a page with a couple dozen (dynamically changeable amount) input fields (mostly text, a few buttons), and when the form is complete/submitted/finalized, it can no longer be edited but can still be viewed. What I did to accomplish this is to declare a string called disabled, and if the form has been finalized, it is set as

```
disabled="disabled=\"disabled\""
```

and otherwise is null. I then place it in evey input tag, so that they will be disabled. This works fine. However, the cursor still changes to a pointer on the buttons and a text cursor on the text boxes. How can I change that? I'm trying with

```
string disabled = (bool)ViewData["Finalized"] ? "disabled = \"disabled\" style=\"cursor:default\"" : null;
```

which renders the quotes within the tags as ". The disable feature works fine, but the cursor is unaffacted.
I've tried rewriting it with single quotes within the string (same result), and with single quotes around the string and double quotes within it (error, too many characters in literal), but have had no success.
Is this something that can be done this way? Or am I going about it in the wrong way?

The resulting output of the above setup is

```
<input maxlength="4" type="text" name="input1" value="1"  disabled = &quot;disabled&quot; style=&quot;cursor:default&quot;/>
```

Forgot to mention, inputs are defined on the page along the lines of this example:

```
<input type="button" id="newtablebutton" class="pctbutton white" value="Add Table" onclick="showbox()" <%: disabled %> />
```

Comment: I would go with a simple fix of a low-opacity div overlaying the page, but all of the meaningful information is contained in scrolling divs, so the scrolling functionality can't be lost.

Comment: How about creating a CSS class for disabled elements where you set the style properties.

Comment: @Zachary - no luck with that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the output is exactly this?

```
<input maxlength="4" type="text" name="input1" value="1"  disabled = &quot;disabled&quot; style=&quot;cursor:default&quot;/>
```

You disabled string is getting html encoded when it's set on the element. The reason is the way you're setting it onto the element.

Change this:

```
<input type="button" id="newtablebutton" class="pctbutton white" value="Add Table" onclick="showbox()" <%: disabled %> />
```

To this:

```
<input type="button" id="newtablebutton" class="pctbutton white" value="Add Table" onclick="showbox()" <%= disabled %> />
```

... and you should be good. The reason is that <%: disabled %> html encodes and <%= disabled %> does not.

Answer (score 1):

When you render any server variable along with the markup in the view you should use `MvcHtmlString.Create` method. It will not encode the special characters when it renders. Try this it will solve your problem.

```
<input type="button" id="newtablebutton" class="pctbutton white" value="Add Table" onclick="showbox()" <%= MvcHtmlString.Create(disabled) %> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **cursor:none** when you don't want the cursor to display.

Try adding something to this effect to your disabled string:

```
onfocus="javascript:if (this.disabled) this.style.cursor = 'none';
```

Comment: cursor:none also has no effect

Comment: What browser are you using? That should work in most browsers.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8. It works when it's applied as a tag in a normal fashion (via CSS or an in-line style attribute), but applying it via jQuery is where I find my problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. If I may ask, why do you have to apply it via jQuery?

Comment: When the form is submitted, I want to disable all of the inputs while it is processed (without reloading the page). Any javascript solution would be great, but I've been using jQuery so it seemed simplest.

Comment: This doesn't work?: document.getElementById('<Element ID>').style.cursor = 'none';

Comment: Try that and let me know if it works. This should make for an interesting experiment.

Comment: Sorry, I explained my response to your answer somewhat poorly. Setting by jQuery (when the form is submitted) works fine. However, if the form is not editable WHEN THE PAGE IS LOADED I have the problem described above.

Comment: I suppose putting a check in $(document).ready or equivalent and setting the cursor then would work, but I'm interested to see if this method can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try setting the input as readonly too, along with it being disabled. I don't know if this will effect the cursor, but it may. Definitely simpler than a jQuery or JS solution.

Comment: Readonly still allows for selection and copy/paste of the text in the field, so the cursor is still a text cursor.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use jQuery!

```
function hideCursor() {
   $("input[disabled='disabled']").css("cursor","default");
}
```

Just call that whenever you want.

Also to make life simpler:

```
function disableForm() {
    $("#myForm input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#myForm input").css("cursor","default");
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I've got just such a function, and I use it when the form is disabled while the page is being viewed, but I would like to have it disabled on load (I know I can use jQuery for this, but the implementation above was already in place for the disabling, and works, so I would like to disable the cursor that way as well, if possible).

Comment: $("#myForm input").css("cursor","default");
This will disable the cursor... I'm a little confused, if you can post the detailed code you are implementing I'll be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add this to your CSS instead of trying to generate the style on each element?

```
input[disabled]
{
    cursor: default;
}
```

(Note that in my tests Chrome would already use the default cursor on a disabled input)